# How to add autoload-function to CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, autoload

I would like to be able to use OOP and create new objects in my controllers in CodeIgniter. So I need to use an autoload-function:

```
function __autoload( $classname )
{
    require_once("../records/$classname.php");
}
```

But how can I add that to CodeIgniter?

Comment: You should link to your other question to better espress your needs ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add your auto loader above to `app/config/config.php`. I've used a similar `autoload` function before in this location and it's worked quite neatly.

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        @include_once(APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT);
    }
}
```

Courtesy of Phil Sturgeon. This way may be more portable. `core` would probably be `records` for you; but check your paths are correct regardless. This method also prevents any interference with loading `CI_` libs (accidentally)

Comment: This works in PHP 5.4, but triggers an error in PHP 5.5. Does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: @tabacitu I'm using it with 5.6.7 and have no problems, use something like [phpab](https://github.com/theseer/Autoload) to generate your class map then include it

Answer (score 0):

the User guide about [Auto-loading Resources](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html) is pretty cleat about it.

> To autoload resources, open the application/config/autoload.php file and add the item you want loaded to the autoload array. You'll find instructions in that file corresponding to each type of item.

Comment: I tried this now and created a file `loader.php` and auto-loaded it as a "config" file. But it looks like the function is executed at load, so I get this error message: `Message: require_once(../records/CI_Exceptions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` Any suggestions?

Comment: probably you need to make your autoload function more "inteligent" for example replace `_` for `/` and make path absolute so this will make CI_Exceptions.php -> CI/Exceptions.php

Comment: That autoloading section isn't auto-loading. It's pre-loading of classes by Codeigniter. What the OP wanted was to auto-load classes when trying to instantiate them, which is what the accepted answer does.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using hooks in order to add this function to your code.
Enable hooks in your config/config.php

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

In your **application/config/hooks.php** add new hook on the "pre_system" call, which happens in core/CodeIgniter.php before the whole system runs.

```
$hook['pre_system'] = array(
    0 => array(         
        'function' => 'load_initial_functions',
        'filename' => 'your_hooks.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks'
    )
);
```

Then in the hooks folder create 2 files:
First: **application/hooks/your_functions.php** and place your **__autoload** function and all other functions that you want available at this point.
Second: **application/hooks/your_hooks.php** and place this code:

```
function load_initial_functions()
{
    require_once(APPPATH.'hooks/your_functions.php');
}
```

This will make all of your functions defined in your_functions.php available everywhere in your code.