# Codeigniter looking for libraries in "core" folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created this Facebook app using ion_auth. In some browsers when you authorize the app it does not log the user in on my server.

I checked the log files and found out this

```
ERROR - 2013-06-10 00:00:01 --> Severity: Warning  --> include_once(application/core/MY_Ion_auth.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory /var/www/html/application/config/production/config.php 378
ERROR - 2013-06-10 00:00:01 --> Severity: Warning  --> include_once(): Failed opening 'application/core/MY_Ion_auth.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') /var/www/html/application/config/production/config.php 378
```

now the config.php line 378 is like

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0) {
        @include_once(APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT);
    }
}
```

ion_auth and go2 both are libraries that are on auto-load ... and they are actually in libraries folder.

any ideas?

Comment: why are you trying to include My_Ion_auth.php in config? You mustn't include anything in config file. Becouse including anything is in the business layer.

Comment: I'm getting this problem. It's appending MY_ to the library class names and looking for them in `application/core`. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 5):

This libraries loading error is related to an older version of the [`__autoload` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6189741/539883) (which allows you to autoload custom base controllers from within `application/core`). `config.php` is the correct / recommended location for this method.

A side effect of the old version is that CI attempts to find in the core directory any custom libraries you load.

The solution is to use the [new version of the autoload method](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/191094/), which is:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include $file;
        }

        elseif (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for the simple straight answer. My log filed were getting pretty big because of this!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you **include the relevant libraries in the constructor of your controller**. For example:

```
class MyOwnAuth extends CI_Controller {

    /*
     * CONSTRUCTOR
     * Load what you need here.
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('url');

        // Load MongoDB library instead of native db driver if required
        $this->config->item('use_mongodb', 'ion_auth') ?
        $this->load->library('mongo_db') :

        $this->load->database();

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters($this->config->item('error_start_delimiter', 'ion_auth'), $this->config->item('error_end_delimiter', 'ion_auth'));

        $this->lang->load('auth');
        $this->load->helper('language');
    }
}
/* End of class MyOwnAuth*/
```

This way you are only loading libraries that are essential for your controller to run. Keeps your code lightweight :)

Comment: tried doing this ... the errors changed to can't recognize $user in $user= $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();"

Comment: Hi Jamil, I think you have a typo in your code: you have somewhere in your code `$user= $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();` and it should be `$user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();`

Comment: Hopefully this has solved your question. If not please let me know. If yes, then I'd appreciate it if you can accept the answer :)

Comment: It did not. It was a typo on stackoverflow.

Comment: What is your constructor in your authorization controller looking like? Here is how mine looks which works perfectly. Please look at the modified code above.