# CodeIgniter Checking Files

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm writing a template_loader for my CodeIgniter project. As usual, I need several security layers for my templates. One of them, which is the very first one, is checking if the files exists or not.

Now, My Problem is: I can't configure what address to give to the template loader. When I use simple php function called 'include()', it works, but with my template_loader function, it fails to work.

Here is my actual page (index.php):

```
<?php
    /**
    Add the page-suitable template from in folder.
    **/ 
    $this->template_loader->load_template('inc/temp_one_col.php');
    // include('inc/temp_one_col.php');

?>
```

And here is my class and template_loader:

```
class Template_loader 
{
    function load_template ($arg)
    {
        $base_name = basename($arg);

        $CI =&  get_instance();

        if(file_exists($arg) === true)
        {                       
                echo 'it is also good.';
                if (pathinfo($base_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'php' ||
                pathinfo($base_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'html'
                )
                {                   
                    $file_name_check = substr($base_name, 0, 4);
                    if($file_name_check === TEMP_FILE_INDICATOR)
                    {                       
                        include($arg);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        redirect($CI->base_url . '/error/show_problem');                    
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                redirect($CI->base_url . '/error/show_problem');    

                }
        }
        else
        {
            redirect($CI->base_url . '/error/show_problem');            
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188727/how-to-add-autoload-function-to-codeigniter (for autoloading function, marked as answer)

Comment: Sorry it seems you misunderstood my question, or I misunderstand your reply. I already have loaded the library in my controller, the only error I get is the address problem. Because file_exists does not find the file given in parameter.

Comment: oh I see, try this out `base_url($arg);` (`base_url()` is in url helper). I am sure that there is just wrong path given to the `file_exists()` even try using CIs constanst as `APPPATH`.. see the full list here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/reserved_names.html

Comment: I have done this now. It fails again. everything is fit when i use include(), but with CI it fails

Comment: Why you're doing this? looks similar to codeigniter views technique. Anyway what's the error you get?

Comment: Mostafa, what are you passing to the function as the $arg parameter?

Comment: Where's the `inc/` folder. show us your folder structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of interest, what are you passing to the function as the `$arg` parameter?

Sounds like you just need to use the correct path to the file, which should be the absolute path to the file in the filesystem.

To get the absolute path you could create a new global variable in your sites index.php to point to your views folder.

**webroot/index.php:**

```
if (realpath('../application/views') !== FALSE)
{   
    $views_path =realpath('../application/views').'/';
    define('VIEWSPATH', $views_path);
}
```

Now you can use this as the base for your `$arg` parameter `VIEWSPATH.$path_to_file`